# Get user's groups in rocketchat using python api

Tags: python, rocket.chat

How can I get rooms(groups) of a user using python API? I have admin access to rocketchat. I tried:

```
from rocketchat_API.rocketchat import RocketChat    

rocket = RocketChat(
    ROCKET_CHAT_ADMIN_USERNAME,
    ROCKET_CHAT_ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    server_url=ROCKET_CHAT_HOST)

rocket.users_info(USER_ID)
```

but it does not contain groups information. I think that I should provide another argument to this method according to the [Rest API](https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/users/info/) but I don't know how.

Comment: by group do you mean `channel` ?

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax I mean rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide additional keyword arguments like this:

```py
rocket.users_info(user_id=USER_ID, fields='{"userRooms": 1}')
```

`userRooms` is the additional field you need to specify according to the Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the REST API, this alternative `spotlight` method be of interest to you as well:

> **GET  /api/v1/spotlight**
>
> Searches for users or rooms that are visible to the user.
>
> https://rocket.chat/docs/developer-guides/rest-api/miscellaneous/spotlight/

And looking at the source code of the Python API:

```
def spotlight(self, query, **kwargs):
        """Searches for users or rooms that are visible to the user."""
        return self.__call_api_get('spotlight', query=query, kwargs=kwargs)
```

> https://github.com/jadolg/rocketchat_API/blob/master/rocketchat_API/rocketchat.py